# Store data-select value of href link in local storage and use it to select dropdown option on new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some links in my navigation bar dropdown that all direct to the same page, but depending on the link that was clicked, it should select a specific select box option on this page. I decided to store the href link value in local storage and call the value when the linked page is loaded using jQuery, but I get the message "null" when the new page is loaded.

This is the html of the navigation bar dropdown links:

```
<a href="newpage.php" data-select="option1">Jackets</a>
<a href="newpage.php" data-select="option2">Shoes</a>
<a href="newpage.php" data-select="option3">Shirts</a>
```

JavaScript to store selected value in local storage:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var linkInput = $('a[href="newpage.php"]').click(function () {
  ($(this).data('select'));
  localStorage.setItem("storelinkInput",linkInput);
  }
```

JavaScript in newpage.php:

```
window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem("storelinkInput"));
  var $select = $('#selector');
  $select.val("storelinkInput");
```

HTML of select box in newpage.php:

```
<form>
  <select id="selector">
    <option value="option1">Jackets</option>
    <option value="option2">Shoes</option>
    <option value="option3">Shirts</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Honestly I am not sure if it is the best solution to use local storage for this purpose, or if it would be better to use PHP for this. Any suggestions that would point me in the right direction are much appreciated!

Comment: The approach is ok, once you got your code fixed & running. There are some lines in the code that do not make sense to me. For example `($(this).data('select'));`, this does nothing at all. I think you want to `localStorage.setItem('storelinkInput', $(this).data('select'))` and `$('#selector').val(localStorage.getItem('storelinkInput'))`..

Comment: Thanks, Lars, for your comment. I will change the code and see if it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lars' comment I could fix the code and now it is running. In case someone is looking for a solution to this or a similar question here is the functional code:

This is the html of the navigation bar dropdown links:

```
<a href="newpage.php" data-select="option1">Jackets</a>
<a href="newpage.php" data-select="option2">Shoes</a>
<a href="newpage.php" data-select="option3">Shirts</a>
```

JavaScript to store selected value in local storage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('a[href="newpage.php"]').click(
      function () {
        var toStore = $(this).data('select');
        localStorage.setItem("storelinkInput", toStore);
      });
});
```

HTML of select box in newpage.php:

```
<form>
  <select id="selector">
    <option value="option1">Jackets</option>
    <option value="option2">Shoes</option>
    <option value="option3">Shirts</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

JavaScript in newpage.php:

```
$('#selector').val(localStorage.getItem("storelinkInput"));
```

It is important to place the second javascript ("$('#selector').val...") after the select box in the html/PHP file.